# MySQL query that returns names of all the customers that purchased more than 2 items in one order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing information about transactions involving customers and salesmen. How do I write MySQL queries that return the following:

- all the customers that purchased more than 2 items in one order, and the name of the salesman in charge
- a list of all the products ordered by customers and their price
- a list of all salesman, and for every salesman how many orders he had
  in the past year, and how many actually worked out

Comment: Please show your attempt, ideally with table structures, sample data and expected output.

Comment: Sample data and desired output (in text format.No pictures!) are highly welcome

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing your database structure, but let's say you have two tables like this:

```
customer
-----------------
id int
name varchar
salesman varchar


purchase
------------------
id int
customer_id int
product_id int
date datetime
etc
```

Then you could have a query

```
SELECT
   customer.name,
   count(*) as purchases
FROM
   customer JOIN purchase on customer.id = purchase.customer_id
GROUP BY
   customer.name
HAVING
   purchases > 2
```

The thing here is use HAVING instead of WHERE. Unlike WHERE which filter data before giving answers HAVING clause can use values you count in your query.

For further reading: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx/